# libinput button scrolling: delay between button press and scroll

Tags: libinput

I'm using libinput to enable "button scrolling" for my trackball, where holding a specific button down causes ball movement to translate to scroll movement.

```
xinput set-prop $TRACKBALL_ID "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1
xinput set-prop $TRACKBALL_ID "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 8
```

However, there's a delay of probably a few hundred milliseconds between pressing the button and scroll-translation starting. The timeline goes like this:

```
+---+---+-------
^   ^   ^
|   |   +-- scrolling starts
|   +-- start moving ball
+-- button down
```

It doesn't matter when I start moving the ball — the point is there's a fixed delay between "button down" and "ok, ready to translate movement to scroll".

It seems that this delay exists to enable dual-mode button use. If I just press and release the button quickly, its normal function (browser "back" button) is executed.

(Interestingly, the cursor is rendered stationary immediately upon pressing the button, even before scroll output begins.)

Is there a way to configure this delay? I'm perfectly happy to sacrifice the dual-mode use if necessary. Even if not configurable, who defines this constant and where? Perhaps I can get it changed in source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value highlighted by @henrebotha and compile libinput yourself to achieve the desired effect.

This delay was frustrating me so I modified the `DEFAULT_BUTTON_SCROLL_TIMEOUT` constant (found in the source [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/blob/master/src/evdev.c) and compiled, which seems to have fixed the issue. Have been testing for the past hour and no weird behavior has been observed.

I followed the steps from [this page](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building.html). Doing everything as root as I was having issues before...

1. Install build dependencies as per the above link (e.g. for me on Ubuntu).

   - `sudo pip3 install meson`.
   - `sudo apt-get install ninja-build`.
   - `sudo apt-get build-dep libinput`.
2. `git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput`.
3. `cd libinput`.
4. Edit `./src/evdev.c:53` to your desired time (`50` was good for me). I.e. from `#define DEFAULT_BUTTON_SCROLL_TIMEOUT ms2us(200)` to `#define DEFAULT_BUTTON_SCROLL_TIMEOUT ms2us(50)`.
5. `sudo meson --prefix=/usr builddir/`.
6. `sudo ninja -C builddir/`.
7. `sudo ninja -C builddir/ install`.
8. Reboot.

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the constant hardcoded in the libinput repo, at `/src/evdev.c:53` (Git commit `df527b07b47f5f512db48f0c30c76137d173e230`):

```
#define DEFAULT_BUTTON_SCROLL_TIMEOUT ms2us(200)
```

Sadly this means it's not configurable.